# No certification check when configure nginx to work as a reverse proxy to forward from http to https

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy, self-signed-certificate

I have two machines. both has nginx installed.

Machine A (Server): has nginx and https enabled on port 4435 with self-signed certification

[image]

Machine B (Client): forward requests on /site_manager uri to server A (https) on port 4435.

[image]

*Note: I didn't install the self signed certification on machine B (Client)*

When make curl from the Client B:

using nginx reverse proxy that redirect connection to machine A -> working and that isn't expected because no certificates

[image]

using curl request directly to machine A -> didn't work and that is expected

[image]

The question: **Do you know why nginx able to make https even when no certifications on the machine?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems nginx bypass/skip the certification check by default.

To enable it you have to add the following lines:
[image]

> The proxy_sl_trusted_certificate is the CA certificate that signed the target server certifications in our case that signed server (A)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your answer and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.